# Remove my likes and other people's reference to me on their facebook page

Tags: facebook

I would like to remove my "like" from an old, now unfriended, friend's page.  How do I do that?  More specifically, I "liked" an event where he said we First Met.  I'd like to remove myself from that event , too, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

1. go to your FB profile page
2. toward the upper right, click the Activity Logs button
3. in the left side bar, click the Likes section
4. scroll down until you find the unwanted item
5. click the Pencil icon to the right of it -> Unlike

http://facebook.com/YOURNAMEHERE/allactivity?privacy_source=activity_log&log_filter=likes

See also the sections "Posts You're Tagged In" (near the top) and "Events" (under "More").